# Menu Problem with CiviCRM 5.13.2

Tags: drupal, civicrm-home

Anyone else getting there menu at the bottom after updating to CiviCRM 5.13.2? Any ideas?

Drupal: 7.66
PHP: 5.6.40 
MYSQL: 5.5.62

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Try clearing the sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c folder, and also go to administer - system settings - cleanup caches.

Comment: Yeah I have tried both and does not work to fix

Comment: Same issue here. No amount of cache clears or templates_c/ scrubs makes a difference.

Comment: I've seen this when I was tracking a mixed content issue: default setting was HTTPS, but certain contents was hard coded HTTP. It leads to JS and/or CSS issues, like your case. Check your HTTPS config at every place, probably the root cause is not in CiviCRM. Check your page source for missing or blocked content, or browser's dev tools.

Comment: Same issue, no amount of cache clearing makes a difference. This is on my localhost with just 1 specific install, works fine with all the others.

Comment: Erik. Check your civicrm.settings.php file. I had a hard coded website link. if (!defined('CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , ()

Comment: @ScottPulver I am unclear about what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Erik I had this in my civicrm.settings.php file. After I changed it fixed the layout

Comment: You mean you emptied the base url? Does that not cause all sorts of other problems?

Comment: No. It was set to something else than the website domain I was using. I changed to the domain in the url and it worked.

Comment: OK, unfortunately my domain is correct :-(

Comment: 99 times out of 100, if I have issues with menus not appearing or the strange appearence of layout, it is becasue I have the wrong base URL defined.  I normally get this when I have cloned a site or use the BuildKit to create something.  Ensuring that the civicrm.settings.php file looks good is my goto first check. The second is clearing out the templates_c directory!

Answer (score 1):

We have seen cases where an update causes theming problems (which then makes a lot of weirdness happen on screen as there is effectively no theme functioning so it looks v wrong). In those cases it involved Garland, and the simple solution was to access the Garland settings and simple resave them

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 7.67  Civi 5.13.4, we fixed this issue by changing the Image Upload URL under Resource URLs to a relative path.

[image]

Comment: P Joseph's solution also worked for me. I had to change it to the absolute paths.. because the (www) htaccess files are tweeked.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it on my local sandbox by enabling the Drupal clean url's.

Comment: Where do you enable Drupal clean url's?

Comment: I think I found: `Administer > Configuration > Search and metadata > Clean URLs`.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by doing the following:
1. clearing the sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c
2. Corrected Resource URL
3. and also go to administer - system settings - cleanup caches & Reset paths