# In CiviCRM 5.13.5 the new menu appears below the actual page or form

Tags: menu, global-menu

in CiviCRM 5.13.5 I get the CiviCRM menu below my main form/page even though I have specified that the menu should replace the website menu.
(see screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Is this similar to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30547/menu-problem-with-civicrm-5-13-2 ?

Comment: it certainly is!

Comment: so mark as Duplicate and remove?

Comment: yes as far as I am concerned :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Menu Problem with CiviCRM 5.13.2](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30547/menu-problem-with-civicrm-5-13-2)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by enabling clean url's in my local Drupal installation.