# WP CivicCRM Menubar styles not loading

Tags: wordpress, civicrm-home, menu

In display preferences I have an option to set the menubar above or below content, but the styles for the menubar are not loading. It just dumps the list of links. Any ideas what the deal is?

[image: menubar screenshot]

Comment: If you check your browser console for errors do you see any errors? -> Particularly any blocking of loading of css files?

Comment: This link is for drupal but is the same symptom: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30547/menu-problem-with-civicrm-5-13-2

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE! You don't give a lot of detail. Are you just setting up or did it work and now it doesn't?

I've seen something like this (though the menu items were part hidden under the LH WordPress menu) when I'm hosting in a subdomain. Possibly because of the symlinks in my hosting provider. I got round this by going to Adminster >> System Setting >> Resource URL (or http://..org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Furl&reset=1 if you can't actually see the menu) and changing the Image Upload URL to http://..org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/

Can't remember now how I worked that out as it isn't obvious!

If that doesn't work you need to provide a few more details.