# Menu Problem with CiviCRM 5.26.0 in Drupal

Tags: drupal

My CiviCRM menu bar doesn't appear at the right place on the page and its stylesheet is not loading.

I have the same symptoms as in question [Menu Problem with CiviCRM 5.13.2](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30547/menu-problem-with-civicrm-5-13-2) but the solutions they offer there do not solve my issue.

Since the picture of the heading at `http://***.be/sites/default/files/ocsr.png` doesn't show up, I discovered that the files under the directory `<drupal_root>/sites/default/files` are not served anymore by `apache` when requested by the browser.

There is a `.htaccess` file in that directory containing:

```
# Deny all requests from Apache 2.4+.
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
  Require all denied
</IfModule>

# Deny all requests from Apache 2.0-2.2.
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
  Deny from all
</IfModule>

# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

My knowledge of `apache` is too poor to understand if this file is the guilty, but in the logs of `apache`, I see entries as:

```
[Tue Jun 09 14:18:54.299253 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 30658] [client 127.0.0.1:42982] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/crm-menubar.4153687684a8323812edc1dc3cdbefbd.css
[Tue Jun 09 14:38:46.732818 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 22455] [client 127.0.0.1:43090] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/drupal/sites/default/files/ocsr.png
```

that seem to be connected directly with my issue.

Since I am a newbie with CiviCRM, I don't have any clue about how to solve this.

Perhaps another useful information: I didn't have time to upgrade to the last version of Drupal 7 up to now. I don't know if the problem is coming from that delay and I don't know what is better: first solve the issue and then upgrade, or the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` file is incorrect.

It should contain the following content:

```
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews
# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>
# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

The remaining lines are added ONLY for private file storage, namely these lines:

```
# Deny all requests from Apache 2.4+.
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
  Require all denied
</IfModule>
# Deny all requests from Apache 2.0-2.2.
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
  Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

**You should check your Drupal configuration, to ensure that you have a separate folder configured for private file storage, this should be outside your web root.**

You should check your configuration against the Drupal documentation here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/install/setting-up-the-files-directory

Comment: I will try that. Thank you. I am trying to understand why I need to have a separate folder configured for private file storage outside my web root. I don't see in https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/install/setting-up-the-files-directory anything in relation to that.

Comment: The entire point of your private files folder is that it's private (i.e. not in your public files path). It is used for files that are delivered via PHP/Drupal and not via the web server.

Comment: See this issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/documentation/issues/1006692

Comment: This blog is useful as well: https://openconcept.ca/blog/mgifford/setting-drupal-7s-private-file-system

Comment: OK. I understood that I don't need private files for now. The `.htaccess` that works for me is containing only the first part of the two ones that you posted in your answer.

Comment: Make sure you turn off (clear!) the private files path in Drupal settings - otherwise Drupal will helpfully recreate the .htaccess it thinks should be there!

Comment: It was not true I didn't need private files. I did for the module Backup and Migrate, but thanks to the hints I found here, I could manage it to make the module save the backups in a directory outside of the Drupal tree. This is an advantage because the backups now go directly to a directory that is synchronised with the cloud.